# replace part of different strings (perl, bash)

Tags: bash, perl, sed, wildcard

I would like to replace text in a csv-file in several lines:

Input:

```
any text,"textA, textB",any text
```

Ouput:

```
any text, textA; textB,any text
```

(i.e.: substitute comma by semicolon in case it is located between two quotation marks, and remove also quotation marks)

I tried sed and wildcards for textA and textB but was not able to print textA and textB in the output file.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -r 's/"([^"]+),([^"]+)"/\1;\2/g' file
any text,textA; textB,any text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with gnu-awk:

```
cat file
any text,"textA, textB",any text

awk -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
     gsub(/,/, ";", $i); gsub(/"/, "", $i)}} 1' file
any text,textA; textB,any text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed, to match the quotes and then capture groups to grab the text after the first quote up to a comma (all text that is not a quote and not a comma (`[^",]*`), then the text after the comma up to the closing quote.

`sed 's/\("\)\([^",]*\)\([,]\)\([^",]*\)\("\)/\2;\4/g' <<< 'any text,"textA, textB",any text'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/"/!b;s//\n/;s//\n/;h;y/,/;/;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2 \1/;ta' file
```

If there are no `"` in the line bail out. Otherwise replace the first two occurances of `"` with newlines and make a copy in the hold space. Translate any `,` to `;` in the pattern space then append the hold space to the pattern space and re-arrange the line using pattern matching. If the substitution were successful then repeat until all `"` have been replaced.

N.B. This presupposes that all `"` are matched.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution using the (standard) T[ext::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Text::ParseWords;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @data = map { s/,/;/g; $_ } parse_line(',', 0, $_);
  print join ',', @data;
}

__DATA__
any text,"textA, textB",any text
```